# WPF MVVM Context Menu Copy/Paste does not work at first time

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, menuitem

I am trying to copy all row values of a datagrid, using "Copy" in "Menu Item"
However, I am getting a weird situation. I have made a context menu in wpf and using mvvm and making command for the same.
Xaml code is as follows:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>                                     
       <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="100" Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}">
      </DataGridTextColumn>                                  
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="KeyNo" Binding="{Binding KeyNo}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

 <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
  <ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Copy"  Command="{Binding 
    Path=DataContext.CopyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
    Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
  </ContextMenu>
 </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Viewmodel code has a command to handle the command parameter which is shown as follows:

```
        private RelayCommand<object> _CopyCommand;

        public RelayCommand<object> CopyCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_CopyCommand == null)
                {
                    _CopyCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(CopyCommandFunction);
                }
                return _CopyCommand;
            }

        }

        private void CopyCommandFunction(object obj)
        {
            //some code to handle obj.
        }
```

Now the problem is: whenever I am debugging the code, it is not hitting the breakpoint in CopyCommandFunction for the first time.
**This part is weird:**
I change the AncestorType to **DataGrid**, which didn't work. But when I changed AncestorType back to **Window**, then it hits the breakpoint of CopyCommandfunction in viewmodel.
Why is this happening ? and what can I do to resolve this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors the first time you try to use CopyCommand?

Comment: People often have problems like these with Menus as they do not appear as part of the tree.  One typical workaround is to use a `BindingProxy`.  You will find many articles and posts describing it if you search.    A `BindingProxy` gives you an easy way to get to your view-model from a menu binding.  You declare an instance of the `BindingProxy` in your resources and then list it as the `Source`  part of your  context menu bindings

Comment: Getting this binding error: Cannot find source: RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1'.

Comment: @Joe, Thanks but I tried the following and it didn't work. 
https://code.4noobz.net/wpf-mvvm-proxy-binding/